# JavaScript Media Source Extensions - Appending after the initialization segment is not working

Tags: javascript, webm, media-source

I have fully working streaming web app using getUserMedia with Media Recorder on the one side and Media Source Extensions on the other side. Transfer is realized through WebSockets.

The only but significant problem happens when viewer reloads the page, because Media Source need initialization segment first (only the first chunk contains it) to be able to append chunks from the middle of the stream.

So I handle the first stream chunk on the server side and get the initialization segment from it. It looks like this:

[image: Initialization segment]

I guess it looks correct, doesnt it?

When I append it to the buffer, all seems to be fine. Buffers ReadyState is "open". But now, when I append some stream chunk from the middle of the stream, ReadyState changes to "ended" and nothing is played.

I am absolutely lost about what can I do to make it work. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: how did you get the initial segment?